# Unable to find htdocs on xampp

Tags: macos, server, xampp, macos-sierra

I have installed XAMPP for macOS Sierra.

I have one icon in application for XAMPP.

I am able to run the server & it's services but I am not able to find the `htdocs` folder.

I have not found it under `\Library\Webserver`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was able to find the htdocs directory. On mac,Under volume tab there is button called 'explore' from there there is the directory.[image]

Comment: Does anyone having problem in copy paste of folder with multiple files within this directory?

Answer (score 24):

Just found out that XAMPP nfs mounts on MacOS are located in following path:

```
/Users/my_name/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs
```

Comment: This is the answer I came here for. For XAMPP-VM on Mac, this is the actual answer. I don't care about the GUI drag-and-drop stuff, I need CLI access. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: This is also helpful in filezilla access

Answer (score 9):

The new version of XAMPP uses a VM for its content, you need to mount the Volume to access htdocs.

[image: XAMPP-VM mount]

More info about differences between old XAMPP and XAMPP-VM:
[XAMPP-VM for Mac](https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20170628.html)

Answer (score 4):

In other to locate the right and active `htdocs` directory of your XAMPP for macOS Sierra, follow the three steps below;

1. Launch your XAMPP and click on the "Start" button,
2. Wait for the *Status* indicator bubble to change from the orange colour to green, then click on the "Volumes" tab (between the "Network" and "Log" tabs),
3. Proceed to click on the "Mount", then "Explore" button;

From the resulting window, you can easily locate your `htdocs` folder.

More details available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgI1LjK-lPM).

Answer (score 0):

Delete the xampp.app, download the new one(I use 5.6.31 php ver) then reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also mount it on your own mac :

```
hatem@Mac:/opt$ sudo mkdir lampp
hatem@Mac:/opt$ sudo mount -t nfs -o resvport,rw 192.168.64.2:/opt/lampp /opt/lampp
```

Then ls and you will find the entire lampp from the VM mounted locally.

Answer (score -1):

I found out that the NEW xampp has file explorer link on it click it and boooooooooom htdocs is there

Answer (score -3):

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles
```

That's where you will find **htdocs**.

Comment: There is no such files.Please see attached screenshot

Comment: Try doing Open Application Folder in the XAMPP control panel.

Comment: I have attached anoither screenshots.There nothing like control panel for xamp

Comment: You could just change the DocumentRoot in httpd.conf (go to Services, Configure and open httpd file or something). This means you do DocumentRoot "/Users/you/myfiles"

Comment: Why there is no htdocs folder ?Why do i need to configure?Where is this httpd.conf file

Comment: Go into the XAMPP control panel, Services, then it should say Configure on the service (you want Apache), then open the httpd conf file. Find DocumentRoot and change it to what you want. I've tried to help you.