# Where to find htdocs in XAMPP Mac

Tags: xampp, htdocs

I cannot find the *htdocs* directory anywhere on XAMPP for Mac.

Many videos on YouTube show people just clicking a button that says "Go to application folder" but on my user interface, it reads: "Go to application" which just opens the localhost page at http://localhost.

Where can I locate the *htdocs* directory?

Comment: Try this, pay attention to the volumes tab part, good luck:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989243/unable-to-find-htdocs-on-xammp

Comment: You can locate your `htdocs` folder using these 3 steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54727322/6381711).

Answer (score 149, accepted):

In the "volumes" tab, you have to mount it first. Then it appears on the desktop as if it were an external USB. All the data is inside it. :D

Comment: how do you increase the size of that volume?

Comment: For filezilla : /Users/my_name/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs see here :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48272238/3904109

Answer (score 42):

I have installed XAMPP version 7.3.11, After starting the Apache and other services, go to volumes tab on XAMPP, and click on mount button,

[image: Mount]

And then Click on explore button,

[image: Explore]

You will get Finder open up with this,

[image: Xampp]

Comment: The mounted volume really messes with the file watchers (e.g. for SCSS compilation). I wish there were a direct path

Answer (score 41):

At least for macbook (os high sierra) go to terminal and type or copy and paste:

```
cd ~/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs
```

Comment: This is a great answer.  How did you figure this out? What are the second and third elements of this path?

Comment: BIG help! Thank you :)

Answer (score 31):

Open xampp application, then do the following:

1. go to: volumes,
2. click the [mount] button, and
3. finally click explore.

Answer (score 10):

Go to Volumes Tab and click **Mount**

[image]

You can find it under Locations in the Sidebar. Click on it.

[image]

Open this folder: Lamp

[image]

You can find the htdocs folder inside Lamp, just like the below screenshot:

[image]

Note: I am using macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 9):

Simple as ...

> From the UI

- Click `Go->Go to Folder` then `/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs`

> From Terminal

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, it should be on the top.. sadly it is downvoted.

Comment: bash: cd: /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs: No such file or directory

Answer (score 9):

you installed Xampp-VM (VirtualMachine), simply instead install one of the "normal" installations and everything runs fine.

Comment: this worked for me this "normal xampp" can be gotten here https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Answer (score 6):

Click volumes, then explore, and then that should open lampp which has htdocs in it.

Answer (score 6):

for each easy and useful access you can add terminal command via editing your bash profile, here how:

open terminal -> type `cd` hit enter.
then type `nano .bash_profile`
then add this line
`alias htdocs="cd ~/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs"`
Now hit `ctrl + o` then hit enter, then hit `ctrl + x`
Now to refresh the terminal commands type the following command

`source .bash_profile`

Now you can use `htdocs` command each time you want to navigate htdocs folder.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to find it:

One way is to open `Finder>Applications>XAMPP(FolderNotTheInstaller)>htdocs`

Another way is `cmd+space` and searches for `manager-osx`,

go to `Welcome` and click the `Open Application Folder`.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For me it was in

```
/Users/your username/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp
```

I am using Mac Os Mojave 10.14.5

Comment: even I have htdocs over there. can it be moved to a more simplified url?

Answer (score 2):

From XAMPP Application window (manager-osx) click => Open Application Folder >> htdocs

Now you opened your target folder.

You can see process by image below

[XAMPP Application window (manager-osx)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2aKA.png)

Open Application Folder

[Application (xamppfiles) folder opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQQ0q.png)

Click on 'htdocs'

[Your target folder 'htdocs' opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMJgd.png)

Now begin your development

Answer (score 1):

Make sure no other apache servers are running as it generates an error when you try to access it on the browser even with a different port. Go to Finder and below Device you will usually see the lampp icon. You can also open the htdocs from any of the ide or code editor by opening files or project once you locate the lampp icon. Make sure you mount the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Simply click in "Go To Application Folder"
[image]

Comment: this is no longer an option

Answer (score 1):

The next moment I installed MAMP, can find the docks in my local.

PFA screenshot.

[image]

Location:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this line to locate and edit the permissions under xampp:

```
chmod 777 ~/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

You installed xampp Vn thats the problem.
Install normal xampp and everything will be fine.

link to nornal xampp: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

1. Download it from the link
2. install it
3. when it opens, Simply click in "Go To Application Folder".

Answer (score 0):

/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs

Answer (score 0):

Go to finder in your Mac

[image]

In Location click the network address.
You will see the Lampp folder. To see this network address yo need to have started xampp application and mounted it.

Click Lampp folder
[image]

You will see the htdocs folder among the folders.

On opening htdocs folder you will find your php applications

[image]

Answer (score -3):

From the Finder menu, click Go->Go to Folder.   Type in /Applications/XAMPP

Comment: That only took me to my applications folder. Sadly. Maybe i should try going to the htdocs folder? I tried but it said it didnt exist.